# Global variable not changing in main C++

Tags: c++, variables, global

I'm new to C++ and I'm learning it by trying to write a Monte Carlo code simulating particles with interacting via a LJ potential (for those who don't know what that is, I'm writing a scientific program to simulate particles).

Many different functions and modules use the same variables so utilizing global variables would be very useful for me. However I have had a hard time finding tutorials or questions in sufficient detail. Either that or I am making some simple errors.

To understand how to use global variables I have started with a main program, a function which reads a text file, and a global file for my variables. In the main I call the function which reads the variables (which are  linked to the global file), but the variable isn't changed in the main program. The input file gives T as 10.

The following code returns:

Read_control says T = 10

LJ says T = 5

lennardjones.cc

```
#include <iostream> 
#ifndef GLOBAL
#define GLOBAL
#include "global.hh"
#endif
#include "read_control.hh"

using namespace std;

int main() {

double T=5;

read_control();

cout << "LJ says T = " << T << endl;

return 0; }
```

read_control.hh

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef GLOBAL
#define GLOBAL
#include "global.hh"
#endif

using namespace std;

void read_control() {

double P, T;

ifstream file;
string u = "useless data";

file.open("control.inp");

file>> u >> u >> P >> T;

file.close();

cout << "Read_control says T = " << T << endl;
}
```

global.hh

```
#ifndef GLOBAL
#define GLOBAL
#endif

extern double P, T;
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Hope the post isn't too long.

Comment: `P` and `T` are not global variables, but *several* function local variables. But you should not be using global variables to begin with.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: 1: I noticed that just after posting this. I moved the line "extern double P, T;" outside the "void global().." scope and it didn't change anything.

2. I assumed that I could state a problem without explicitly stating a question. A suitable question would be: What do i have to change so that the code prints "LJ says T = 10".

Comment: Remove the `void global(){` and `}` lines from global.hh and move the `double P, T;` line outside teh file scope in read_control.hh.  (Also, don't define functions in header `hh` files.)  It would be nicer if you either (at least) put the globals in their own namespace, or (better) encapsulated your globals in a static singleton class with accessor methods, or (best) eliminated them entirely by moving them into the specific classes where they are used.  But these are more advanced topics of Object Oriented Design.

Comment: I'd like to offer one comment on the way you're preventing multiple inclusion of header files.  If you follow the convention spelled out here in Google's style guide (which is widely adopted in the industry), then you don't need to extra checks on the definition of GLOBAL everywhere you want to #include "global.hh":  http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#The__define_Guard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void read_control() {

double P, T;

ifstream file;
string u = "useless data";

file.open("control.inp");

file>> u >> u >> P >> T;

file.close();

cout << "Read_control says T = " << T << endl;
}
```

The variable `T` declared here is a local variable for this function and its scope ends with the function , it is **not** a global variable.

Here is how you do it

```
#include <iostream> 
#ifndef GLOBAL
#define GLOBAL
#include "global.hh"
#endif
#include "read_control.hh"

using namespace std;
int T = 100 // T is now a Global variable

int main() {

double T=5;  // T is also a Local variable for the function main()

read_control();
cout<<T; // will print 5 as it is what the Local var T is
cout<<::T ; // will print 100 , i.e the value of Global variable

cout << "LJ says T = " << T << endl;

return 0; }
```

**NOTE** if you used such declaration of `T` , T is global variable to `main()` and all the functions defined after that , but not for the `read_control()` function , as it is defined before . To do that, just include it after our global declaration

```
#include <iostream> 
#ifndef GLOBAL
#define GLOBAL
#include "global.hh"
#endif

using namespace std;
int T = 100 // T is now a Global variable
#include "read_control.hh"
int main() {

double T=5;  // T is also a Local variable for the function main()

read_control();
cout<<T; // will print 5 as it is what the Local var T is
cout<<::T ; // will print 100 , i.e the value of Global variable

cout << "LJ says T = " << T << endl;

return 0; }
```

`::` is scope resolution operator in c++. You read about it here : http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/facilities/ComputingFacilities/systems/cluster/vac-7.0/html/language/ref/clrc05cplr175.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I'm not used to scope as a concept. This made everything very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your only using local variables.

Create a header (or rename your "global.hh") "lennardjones.hpp" and declare the global variable T (awful name) with *extern double T;* and define (and initalize) the variable *double T = 5;* **outside your main function** in the source file "lennardjones.cc"

Now include the header lennardjones.hpp inside both source files with *#include "lennardjones.hpp"*. Remove the definition of the variable T from the function read_control() and main().

Furthermore:
Put your include guards in the header (doing work once for all is the purpose of a header) and stop using global variables if you don't need them. I'm pretty sure you don't need global variables. I can only advise you to read a good book about C++, the current code looks like mixed knowledge from mediocre to awful half completed tutorials from the web.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the name is awful? T stands for temperature.

Comment: And thanks for the reply. Your explanation make sense to me now after reading the other answer.

Comment: Yep. It is even not a name, I just a meaningless letter for subsequent readers of your code. Furthermore T is heavly used in templates. The usual variable names for "quick code" inside very simple blocks of code are i, j, k and so on. Suggest, use the name temperature (not temp or tmp, could easly confused with temporary). A global variable is "not local to a simple block", it visible to everyone, so a good name is really important.

Comment: I was reading Accelerated C++ for the first 5-7 chapters, but thought that the more advanced features were unnecessary for my application. I realise now that I should have looked at a more in depth book for this. Most of the tutorials/explanations on the internet are incomplete (or at least are not clear enough for me).

I have seen a lot of people dismissing the use of global variables. However this is a program I am writing purely for myself, and I am somewhat modelling it on my supervisor's Fortran code in which he used modules for variables which were used universally.

Comment: I'm not sure if the usual arguments against global variables apply in this specific case. However, if I do find that they are a problem I will be happy to look for a different solution.

Comment: Nobody will blame you for a global variable in a simple program (I'm using them too sometimes). But especially because your learning, you should stick with sane rules of well written code and avoid a bad habit.